# Using a jQuery selector as a string literal

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I would like to use a jQuery selector as a string literal and not as an ojbect.

Is this possible with JS?

**Markup**

```
    <levelTwo>
        <head0>
            <something></something>
        </head0>
    </levelTwo>
```

**JS**

```
 var jamie = $('something').parent();

 //Desired useage
 typeOf(jamie) 
 // String
 console.info(jamie); 
 //"head0"
```

Comment: use jsfiddle.net for demo

Comment: why do we need a demo...? The problem is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('something').parent().prop("tagName").toLowerCase()
```

You can also define a `.toString()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rq6Kz/

```
$.fn.toString = function() {
      return this[0] ? this[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() : "";
};

console.info($("div").toString()); //"div"
```

This is implicitly called in some contexts, like alert:

```
alert($("div")); //alerts "div"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rq6Kz/1/

Comment: how did i not know about prop :O? and within this context.

Comment: A nice illustration of the difference between properties and attributes!

Comment: You're overwriting toString by creating a jQuery version of toString?

Comment: yes, normally it always just returns `"[object Object]"` which is completely useless so I guess it's ok.

Comment: indeed :) I'm still loving the use of prop. Good times.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use jQuery on XML, is a little trickier. To acccess the DOM element from the jQuery selector you can use "[0]".

```
//<head0 name="head1">text</head0>
$(element)[0].getAttribute('name');
//result head1
$(element)[0].innerHTML();
//result "text"
$(element)[0].valueOf();
//results <head0 name="head1">
$(element)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
//results head0
```

You may also need the parseXML from jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: thanks for the idea, but this will mean editing the markup. If i was going to do that i could easily just add the class or any attr and get it that way.

Comment: why to modify the markup ? the example is just to show how can you access all the attributes, the last command works for your example.